# Can't launch javaFx application with intellij anymore

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am developping a JavaFx application with IntelliJ Idea, and until today, all worked fine, but now for no reason (maybe i did something wrong without knowing it) whenever i try to launch a JavaFx application i get this on the console :

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

I already tried to re-install IntelliJ but it didn't worked. Even for a new JavaFx application i get this error, and no window is launched and i get the same message.

I can't find anyone who had this problem so i am asking here hoping to find an answer :)

Comment: Have you tried to launch your app on another computer?

Comment: Do you happen to have an nVidia GPU, and updated your drivers recently?

Comment: I think @sillyfly is on the right track... Assuming you are on windows, a `0xC0000409` Process Termination Value indicates (based on some  googling) "Stack corruption detected" and can often be attributed to a registry corruption or (often) video driver corruption/problems. And if it was working before, you need to start with the age old troubleshooting question "What's changed?"

Comment: Yes, it was the new Nvidia driver wich was causing this problem. I installed the previous version and everything works fine again. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 6):

The problem comes with the latest **Nvidia Driver version: 378.49**, this driver breaks some java.exe execution such as Android application compilations.

I rolled back my Nvidia Driver in Windows 10 to version **376.33** following these steps:

1. Right Click in the Windows button (left-bottom side of screen)
2. Click Device Manager
3. Double-click on Display Adapters
4. Double-click on your NVIDIA GPU
5. Select the "Driver" tab
6. Select "Upload Driver..."
7. Select "Browse my computer for driver software"
8. Select "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"
9. Select "NVIDIA Geforce Version: 21.21.13.7633 [11/12/2016] from the given list
10. Click "Next" in the right-bottom corner
11. After the driver has been installed, reboot the system.

After the reboot java.exe should work as usual.

Hope this helps more people in the same situation, I wasted 2 days looking for solutions going around Gradle, Android and Java re-installations.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem as you do. As some commenters (@sillyfly and @Javaru) pointed out, the problem is with the new Nvidia drivers. Assuming you are on windows, do the following:

1. Click Start
2. Click Control Panel
3. In the left pane, click Device Manager
4. Double-click on Display Adapters
5. Double-click on your NVIDIA GPU
6. Select the Driver Tab
7. Click on Roll Back Driver

This will roll back your Nvidia drivers to the previous version. Hopefully it works now.

Comment: Thank you very much, i re-installed my previous Nvidia driver and everything works fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Problem comes from Nvidia drivers. I had the same error and disabling the nvidia gpu from the device manager caused it to be fixed.

Comment: Yes, it was the new Nvidia driver wich was causing this problem. I installed the previous version and everything works fine again. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

So as it was told on the other answers, the problem came form the last Nvidia Driver : 378.49 
I re-installed the older version (376.33) and all worked fine again.

In my case i have the Nvidia 960M.

Thanks everyone for your help.