# JavaFX application does not run under IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am using the unchanged sample application that IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3 generate. When I try to run it it says "**Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)**"
However, when I run the exact same source code in Eclipse everything goes fine.
P.S: I am using the Default Settings in IntelliJ ID.

Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Sample.fxml

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
</GridPane>
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;

public class Controller {
}
```

**UPDATE**: I solved this Problem by deactivating my nVidia Card on my Laptop.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896921/cant-launch-javafx-application-with-intellij-anymore)  (can't mark as duplicate as it has no answer yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is usually linked with nVidia graphics drivers every now and then. I can confirm that it is due to 1/24/2017 update. [Roll back to December 2016 update for now until they fix this issue.](http://www.nvidia.com/download/find.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, install the 376.33 driver from Nvidia and it should work again.